# When we try to solve the hard problem like 'ABC conjecture',should we first examine if it is a proposition that neither prove nor disprove

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, incompleteness, abc-conjecture

In mathematic logic,Godel's incompleteness theorem tell us that  a proposition that neither prove nor disprove is exist.so did every famous hard problem need to be examine first?

Comment: I don't believe we should encourage fist examinations

Comment: @Ian That's not true in general. There are a lot of statements whose proof of relative independence to even a student of mathematical logic is no harder than any other homework a student of analysis might face. There is, however, a good reason that 'classical questions' in mathematics have rarely been proved to be independent from our background theory. See my answer below.

Comment: @Ian The indepence of $\operatorname{CH}$ is easily established, once a student knows about forcing. In fact, one direction was given as an exercise to me in a set theory class I attended. Sure, one needs machinery and developing that is hard. However, the same applies to all kinds of homework assignments in analysis and no analysist would call them 'hard'.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche it was an error in the title. English is not the first language for the OP. He edited in the correct word, first, about two hours after your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us take $\operatorname{ZFC}$ as our background theory and let us assume its consistency (for convenience).

You're right that *Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem* guarantees that there are statements $\phi$ whose truth value is not decided by our theory. In fact, over the last 50+ years (more than that, if we also consider the work by Mostowski and co on $\operatorname{ZFA}$) not only have we proved the relative independence of all kinds of statements, we have considerably improved our tools to do so. The most important tool is *Cohen's method of forcing*, originally introduced to prove the relative independence of the *axiom of choice* and the *continuum hypothesis*.

Another important tool to settle questions of independence is *inner model theory*. Sometimes we can prove (the consistency) of a certain statement $\phi$ by adding additional axioms to our theory. The question then becomes whether these additional axioms were necessary. Maybe there was a prove in $\operatorname{ZFC}$, but we weren't clever enough to find it? Inner model theory, sometimes, enables us to prove the necessity of certain additional axioms that provably don't follow from $\operatorname{ZFC}$. This is another method to prove the relative independence of $\phi$.

That being said, when it comes to 'classical' questions in mathematics, there aren't any convincing independence results that I know of. And there is a good reason for that. A consequence of *[Shoenfield's Absolutness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem)* is that forcing and certain methods of inner model theory cannot prove the relative independence of most classical questions, since these are usually of complexity at most $\Pi^1_2$ or $\Sigma^1_2$. This is true for $\operatorname{P} \text{ vs. } \operatorname{NP}$, the Riemann hypothesis, the ABC conjecture, the Goldbach conjecture, the Collatz conjecture, ...

The consensus seems to be that these questions are in fact not independent, but I'm not really interested in this sort of speculation. There are however two mathematical facts about these sorts of problem I am definitely interested in:

1. If one of these problems is independent, it seems like we need much finer control over our universe to prove this fact. Therefore, much like Cohen's work on forcing, settling the independence of one of these results would likely lead to a whole bunch of new and exciting mathematics. There is some ongoing work in this direction, but I know way too little to talk about it.
2. Another consequence of Shoenfield's absoluteness is that if we are able to answer one of these question via forcing or in $L$ or in an inner model that doesn't rely on so-called 'small large cardinals', then this already implies that it was provable in $\operatorname{ZFC}$ to begin with. This allows mathematicians to use a whole lot of additional machinery to tackle those questions without abandoning their philosophical (dis-)beliefs on certain set theoretical questions. Unfortunately, it seems, that this additional machinery isn't very applicable in these scenarios, but who knows? (I'd love a proof of, say, Riemann's Hypothesis to rely on $\Diamond$ in a fundamental way, i.e. in a way that it isn't clear how to get rid of this assumption without referring to some absoluteness argument).